# Assign role or grant permissions for WP user then he collects some points

Tags: wordpress, drupal, permissions, user-generated-content

Lets begin from the start:
I want to make a website where users could generate content. It will be based on Wordpress and am using TDO Mini Forms to let users submit content. I have also added CubePoints plug-in to grant points for my users.

I want user to get some points for  **approved** submission and then he earns, for example, 100 points his posts would be published instantly. To my mind hat can be achieved by granting the user a new role with more permissions or modify permissions for that particular user.

Can I do it with Wordpress I will I have to go back to Drupal and make it happen with modr8 and Rules modules?

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress has a class for managing users called WP_User defined in /wp-includes/capabilities.php

So to change a users's role you could say:

```
$user = new WP_User( $target_user_id );
$user_points = method_to_get_user_points();

if( $user_points > 100 ){
    $user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );
    $user->add_role( 'editor' );
}
```